# php bin2hex, base64_encode; different input same output (in loop)?

Tags: php, hash, decode, encode

I trying to create an array of filename hashes (key) and filenames (value), but most functions I use don't seem to work like I want them to...

Why are these functions when used in a loop resulting in the same output string while the input string varies? md5 and sha1 don't have this problem, but aren't reversible and that's needed.

```
foreach ($files as $file)
{
  debug(array(bin2hex($file), $file));
}

// result
app/views/helpers/monolith.php (line 45)

Array
(
    [0] => 2f686f6d652f6d746572736d697474656e2f7075626c69635f68746d6c2f6170702f707269766174652f6d622f323031302f31322e706466
    [1] => /home/mtersmitten/public_html/app/private/mb/2010/12.pdf
)


app/views/helpers/monolith.php (line 45)

Array
(
    [0] => 2f686f6d652f6d746572736d697474656e2f7075626c69635f68746d6c2f6170702f707269766174652f6d622f323031302f31312e706466
    [1] => /home/mtersmitten/public_html/app/private/mb/2010/11.pdf
)


app/views/helpers/monolith.php (line 45)

Array
(
    [0] => 2f686f6d652f6d746572736d697474656e2f7075626c69635f68746d6c2f6170702f707269766174652f6d622f323031302f31302e706466
    [1] => /home/mtersmitten/public_html/app/private/mb/2010/10.pdf
)
```

I hope this example is more clear...

Comment: I can't speak to `bin2hex()` - maybe it just uses part of the input string or chokes on dots or something - but `base64_encode()` should work fine.

Comment: You should look again. The keys are indeed different. `3132` is the hex-encoding for 12.pdf and `3131` for 11.pdf. Maybe you should explain your use case. As the keys you are using now are just obfuscated filenames.

Comment: I posted a better (simple) example...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In fact the strings are different. You should check more carefully. They are the same for the most part, because both **bin2hex** and **base64_encode** encode the sequence of bytes and do not generate a hash like **sha1** or **md5**.

**bin2hex** just converts every character in the string to its hex value and as for **base64**, check the [wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64) to see exactly why the string is the same for large part of the outcome

Answer (score 2):

```
 ... f6d622f323031302f31322e706466
                         ^
                       1 2 . p h p
 ... f6d622f323031302f31312e706466
                         ^
                       1 1 . p h p
 ... f6d622f323031302f31302e706466
                         ^
                       1 0 . p h p
```

Your "hashes" are different at the spot I've indicated. bin2hex isn't encryption or hashing, it simply takes each character of the input string and converts it into the string version of its hexadecimal ascii code.

Comment: Thanks a million! Do you think bin2hex is suited for passing file names to an url?

Comment: No. bin2hex has a best & worst-case size increase of 2x - it ALWAYS doubles the length of a string. why not just use urlencode()? Best case is no change in length, worst case is double, average case is only a few bytes more.

Comment: Any string can be an array key, including an empty string.

Comment: really? You're probably true (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2316862/php-array-key-encoding/2316898#2316898)