# using chinese characters as php associative array keys

Tags: php, arrays, utf-8, cjk

So I tried to use Chinese characters as the keys for my PHP associative array, but then when I print_r'ed the array, it printed out a whole bunch of garbage instead.

What needs to be done so that I can use Chinese characters for my PHP array keys?

Displaying chinese characters as string work fine though. It's just when I placed them as array keys when it stops working...

eg:

```
$j = array();
$j[utf8_encode('大')] = 1;
$f = array_keys($j);
echo utf8_decode($f[0]);
```

Comment: Did you include something like this `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />` when you print_r ?

Comment: what version of php are you using?

Comment: @ajreal yea even with that it's not showing....@juand I'm using 5.3.5

Comment: check this out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2316862/php-array-key-encoding

Comment: Are you sure you putting the Chinese character in UTF-8 correctly? I pretty sure is not a problem for me, because I do that very frequently :p

Comment: @ajreal yea I did this: $j = array();
$j[utf8_encode('大')] = 1;
$f = array_keys($j);
echo utf8_decode($f[0]);

Comment: as well as that exact meta tag on the head tags

Comment: oh, I think you might need to include your code into the question.

Comment: is there anything wrong with the code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To show case a very simple case of using Chinese character in associate key :-

```
php > $a = array("一定可以"=>TRUE);
php > var_dump($a["一定可以"]);
bool(true)
php > print_r($a);
Array
(
    [一定可以] => 1
)
```

Here is the example if you apply `utf8_encode` and `utf8_decode`:

```
php > $j = array(); $j[utf8_encode('大')] = 1; $f = array_keys($j); echo utf8_decode($f[0]);
大
php > print_r($f);
Array
(
    [0] => å¤§  /* this is garbled */
)
php > print_r($j);
Array
(
    [å¤§] => 1 /* this is garbled too */
)
```

One possible way to overcome:

```
php > print_r(utf8_decode(var_export($j, TRUE)));
array (
  '大' => 1,
)
```

Comment: In PHP 8 some chinese words do not work as index.
For example 汽车

Answer (score 0):

Some PHP functions are known to have poor UTF-8 support, see: [UTF-8 in PHP](http://flourishlib.com/docs/UTF-8)