# UTF-8 Encode Issue with array_key

Tags: php, arrays, json, utf-8

I have seen many issues related to the UTF-8 encoding issue, but most are trying to encode array values.

My problem is with the array **key**.

I want to encode an array that contains keys with special characters.

This is how my array looks without `json_encode`:

```
array(2) {
  ["Paição"]=>
  string(8) "Paição"
  ["São"]=>
  string(10) "São Paulo"
}
```

With `json_encode($array)`:

```
{
  "Pai\\u00e7\\u00e3o": "Paição",
  "S\\u00e3o": "São Paulo"
}
```

Things I have tried so far to fix this:

1. `utf8_encode()`
2. `JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE`
3. `$array = array_map('htmlentities',$array); $json = html_entity_decode(json_encode($array));`

Comment: And your problem is...

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP Array Key encoding?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2316862/php-array-key-encoding)

Answer (score 0):

You can try to `urlencode()` your strings before `json_encode()`, then `url_decode()` the return value of `json_encode()`.

Answer (score 0):

if you are view json_encode() result in your browser, maybe adding :

```
header('Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8');
```

or manually add the line to your header:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
```

will solve your problem